# How do I force my Sim to go to work?

Tags: the-sims-4

My sim is going to be late for work in just a few minutes. No automatic action to go to work popped up while he was eating and chatting with his daughter. Is there any way to force him to go?

Answer (score 9):

Your Sim was eating and chatting!

While Sims will autonomously generate a "Go to Work" action at the appropriate time, if they're in the middle of something else, they will prefer to finish that before leaving the lot.

With something like a conversation, this can be quite some time!

To fix this, you need to cancel the conversation manually, by clicking the action in the action queue in the bottom left. If you accidentally cancel the go to work action (or it has otherwise disappeared), click your sims' phone for the option to "Go to work" (or school!) manually.

Comment: Priorities man, I'm talking. Work can wait.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the work tab at the bottom right when you are late a button appears that says go to the work. Once the button is clicked go to work will be added to your action queue.

Comment: But you may still need to cancel any other actions if you queued them yourself.